# Google rank and HTTP/HTTPS site

Tags: tls

We have SSL on our site, however we have some legacy applications that do not support SSL, what to do in this case?

In order for them to work correctly will I have to leave HTTP and HTTPS active?

How does Google rank works in this case?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your Google page rank is not really relevant to the security of your website. This question would be more fitting for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sorry, i'll ask there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of the question, you could considere setting up a reverse proxy (Apache or nginx) in front of the legacy apps and have the SSL processing on the proxy. If you have full control on the datacenter, the proxy and the application can run on different machines, if you do not, they should run on same machine for obvious security reasons.

The second part (Google rank) is off topic here.